# Truncate ellipsis without width

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I'm trying to achieve a responsive list width text-overflow: ellipsis; in the first cell that looks like this:

A one-lined text that is too long and has to be... | Button 2 |

The whole list should have width: 100%; to be as large as the device. I can't set a fixed width on Button 2  since the application is multilingual (a max-width should be possible though).

I can try whatever I want, the ... only appears when I set a fixed width. How can I tell the middle cell to "use the space available" without the help of JavaScript?

**Getting Output :**

John Doe1       (2)
John Doesdfsf...(3)
Jo1             (4)

**Expected output :**

John Doe1(2)
John Doesdfsf...(3)
Jo1(4)

CSS:

```
.truncate-ellipsis {
        display: inline-block;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis; 
        -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
         width: 20%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="validateCtrl">
<ul>
<li><label class="truncate-ellipsis">{{title1}}</label>({{count1}})</li>
<li><label class="truncate-ellipsis">{{title2}}</label>({{count2}})</li>
<li><label class="truncate-ellipsis">{{title3}}</label>({{count3}})</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/24330/)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is working with max-width also:

```
.truncate-ellipsis {
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis; 
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    max-width: 20%;
}
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/24348/